# Cannot Pass Data to another Activity

Tags: android

I don't know where I am going wrong. all information sources say this is how it's done.a simple pass to here and that's it. What do I have to change so that I can simply pass a number to my second activity? 
Here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button returnBtn;
EditText senderText;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    returnBtn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    senderText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    returnBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String s = senderText.getText().toString();
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("number", s);
            startActivity(i);   
        }
    }); 
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Second activity is

```
package com.example.returningnumbers;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

TextView showNum;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second_info);
    showNum = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String extraData = intent.getExtras().getString("number");
    showNum.setText(extraData);

}
```

}

Logcat information

```
05-23 19:39:38.520: E/Trace(848): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
    05-23 19:39:39.639: D/libEGL(848): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
    05-23 19:39:39.649: D/(848): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x2a154d08, tid 848
    05-23 19:39:39.893: D/libEGL(848): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
    05-23 19:39:39.920: D/libEGL(848): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
    05-23 19:39:40.220: W/EGL_emulation(848): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
    05-23 19:39:40.260: D/OpenGLRenderer(848): Enabling debug mode 0
    05-23 19:39:45.010: D/AndroidRuntime(848): Shutting down VM
    05-23 19:39:45.030: W/dalvikvm(848): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
    05-23 19:39:45.120: E/AndroidRuntime(848): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    05-23 19:39:45.120: E/AndroidRuntime(848): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.returningnumbers/com.example.returningnumbers.SecondActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    05-23 19:39:45.120: E/AndroidRuntime(848):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
    05-23 19:39:45.120: E/AndroidRuntime(848):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
    05-23 19:39:45.120: E/AndroidRuntime(848):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
    05-23 19:39:45.120: E/AndroidRuntime(848):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
    05-23 19:39:45.120: E/AndroidRuntime(848):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    05-23 19:39:45.120: E/AndroidRuntime(848):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    05-23 19:39:45.120: E/AndroidRuntime(848):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
    05-23 19:39:45.120: E/AndroidRuntime(848):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    05-23 19:39:45.120: E/AndroidRuntime(848):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    05-23 19:39:45.120: E/AndroidRuntime(848):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    05-23 19:39:45.120: E/AndroidRuntime(848):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    05-23 19:39:45.120: E/AndroidRuntime(848):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    05-23 19:39:45.120: E/AndroidRuntime(848): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    05-23 19:39:45.120: E/AndroidRuntime(848):  at com.example.returningnumbers.SecondActivity.onCreate(SecondActivity.java:20)
    05-23 19:39:45.120: E/AndroidRuntime(848):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
    05-23 19:39:45.120: E/AndroidRuntime(848):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
    05-23 19:39:45.120: E/AndroidRuntime(848):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
    05-23 19:39:45.120: E/AndroidRuntime(848):  ... 11 more
    05-23 19:39:45.442: D/dalvikvm(848): GC_CONCURRENT freed 100K, 8% free 2719K/2940K, paused 78ms+118ms, total 548ms
    05-23 19:39:48.102: I/Process(848): Sending signal. PID: 848 SIG: 9`
```

Comment: What happens when you compile and run this code? Also, why are you sending a number as a `String` rather than as an `int`, `long`, `double`, or `float`?

Comment: p.s. Look *very* closely at this line: `String extraData = intent.getExtras().getString("nunber");`. Do you see the problem?

Comment: Sorry for the typo, that was on post edit, getting rid of my comments to clean up the code. The Error I get honestly is that it stops working. If I comment out the  "showNum.setText it opens the activity just fine, without showing obviously the updated number. Also, I'm passing a string just to display a string.

Comment: @user2414926 check the edit in my answer posted below. you are trying to findviewbyid with out setting the content to activity. that causes nullpointerexception

Comment: @user2414926 what's on line 20 in SecondActivity.java

Comment: Usually you are setting your content view before you are retrieving your UI components.  I am surprised that you don't see null pointer errors when retrieving your showNum TextView.  That actually looks like that IS your problem after reading your error code once more.

Comment: @JaySnayder i already mentioned the same in my answer in the edit. seems the user has not taken notice of the same

Comment: @user2414926 For future reference, you should copy and paste your code exactly as what you are compiling. This will reduce introducing other errors unrelated to your question.

Comment: @Code-Guru Thank you, I will do so.

Comment: @Raghunandan I have edited in my IDe, let me update the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  String extraData = intent.getExtras().getString("nunber");
```

Should be

```
  String extraData = intent.getExtras().getString("number");
```

In your first activity you have

```
    i.putExtra("number", s);
```

In your second activity you have

```
    intent.getExtras().getString("nunber");  // keys don't match
```

Edit:

```
     setContentView(R.layout.second_info); // this should come first
     showNum = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1); // initialize textview
     Intent intent = getIntent();
     String extraData = intent.getExtras().getString("number"); //get value using key
     showNum.setText(extraData); //set text with the value
```

Comment: I formatted it like this, thank you for the comments too. I'm new to this stuff. I still get the program crashing. :(

Comment: @user2414926 have you changed as posted in the edit section?. if u still have problems post the logcat details of the crash for further help

Comment: Added the logcat, I have changed it to exactly as you have it.

Comment: @user2414926 what's on line 20 in second activity? have you done as shown in edit?

Comment: Yeah. I literally have it set as you have it set.

Comment: @user2414926 then what is line no 20 in SecondActivity

Comment: String extraData = intent.getExtras().getString("number");

Comment: @user2414926 Log the extraData and check

Comment: How can I log the specific line? if you don't mind me asking. I'm new to all of this, even asking a question onto here. Again thank you for your patience and time. I truly appreciate it.

Comment: @user2414926 http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html. check the developer site

Comment: No dice, cannot get it show the log.d possibly not doing it right. Would you like me to update my code with the log stuff here?

Comment: Log.d("logging...", extraData );

Comment: Yeah that seems to be the problem. if I comment out the line                 String extraData, then it'll open up no prob. so I'm checking now where it can be

Comment: Hey, thank you for your help, I got it to work! you're incredible dude thanks! teaching me debugging skills and everything. Can't thank you enough man.

Answer (score 1):

maybe the typo nunber?

```
String extraData = intent.getExtras().getString("nunber");
```

Comment: Sorry for the typo, that was on post edit, getting rid of my comments to clean up the code. not the problem I'm having. It's when I ask showNum to get the string, it  will crash my program. and yes extraData gets string from "number" not nunber, sorry about that again.

Answer (score 1):

You should call `setContentView()` before calling `findViewById()`. My personal preference is to call `setContentView()` immediately after `super.onCreate()` so that I know the rest of the `onCreate()` method is less likely to break.

Comment: Thank you. I will note this down for future projects :D